# Top-Margin Value not doing anything?

Tags: html, css, margins

I know this question has been asked before. I'm just practicing web design, and pretending to create a website for a martial arts school (Nashville Self-Defense is not a real business).

I'm having a problem, the top-margin value of #Slogan does not seem to be working. As a matter of fact, getting top and bottom margins to work has been a lingering problem I've continually encountered.

**The result:**

[image: This isn't what's supposed to happen!]

Can anyone solve this?

```css
#Title {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: greenyellow;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  height: 42px;
}

#Title h1 {
  font-family: Stencil, sans-serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 9px;
}

#Slogan {
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 14%;
  margin-top: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <div id="TopofPage">
    <div id="Title">
      <h1>Nashville Self-DEfense</h1>
      <div id="Slogan"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="SocialMedia"></div>
    <!--not shown in image-->
  </div>
<div id="TopMenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">HOME</a></li>
      <li><a href="#news">CLASSES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">STORE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `none` isn't a valid margin value. `margin-top: 0` would be more appropriate. Or is that not the problem you're referring to?

Comment: It's not clear what you are expecting. margin-top and margin-bottom won't work as you haven't assigned any value to it.

Comment: The gap isn't the top margin of #Slogan, it's the bottom margin of the h1 element.

Comment: @fubar it's still not working, #Slogan won't budge.

Comment: @TheGuy445 I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `margin-top:none;` use `margin-top: 0px !important`

Comment: Why is `!important` required here?

Comment: To override any previous style.

Comment: I know what it does, but why are you suggesting to use it when there are no competing CSS rules?

Answer (score 0):

It has to be 
`margin-top: 0;` 
not
 `margin-top: none;`

next thing is it go higher on '0' as long as the previous element(#title h1) has margin set.

Comment: `top-margin` is not a valid CSS property.

Comment: yeah. margin-top whatever.

Comment: @Dimek i've even tried adding a margin-bottom, yet it still won't budge.